# Error while starting the azure databricks cluster

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I setup a Databricks instance on Azure using terraform. The deployment seems to be good. But, I am getting the following error when creating/starting a new cluster,

```
Message
Cluster terminated. Reason: Cloud provider launch failure

Help
A cloud provider error was encountered while launching worker nodes.

See Knowledge base: Cloud provider initiated terminations for remediations.

Search for error code NetworkingInternalOperationError
Details

Azure error code: NetworkingInternalOperationError

Azure error message: An unexpected error occured while processing the network profile of the VM. Please retry later.
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: FWIW we are suddenly experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually such errors are returned when there are temporary problems with underlying VM infrastructure.  Usually they mitigated very fast, so you just need to try later, although it makes sense to check [Azure Databricks](https://status.azuredatabricks.net/) and [Azure](https://status.azure.com) status pages - they may show if outage is in progress.